# How do I count instances of duplicates of rows in pandas dataframe, remove all duplicates except unique ones, then add counts column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

The title says it all. Starting with something like

[image]

...I'd like to end up with something like

[image]

where the Quantity column has counts of how many duplicates of a particular row were present in the original dataframe. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you :)

I've tried adding a Quantity column full of ones to the original dataframe and then using

```
df.groupby(['Date','Product_ID'],as_index=False).agg({"Quantity":"sum"})
```

This gets me the correct counts, but I lose the other columns like Category/Brand_ID/etc.

Answer (score 1):

With the following toy dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": ["a", 1, 8, "a", 3, "a", 8, "c", 6, "c", 8],
        "col2": ["a", 1, 8, "a", 3, "a", 8, "c", 6, "c", 8],
        "col3": ["a", 1, 8, "a", 3, "a", 8, "c", 6, "c", 8],
    }
)

print(df)
# Output
   col1 col2 col3
0     a    a    a
1     1    1    1
2     8    8    8
3     a    a    a
4     3    3    3
5     a    a    a
6     8    8    8
7     c    c    c
8     6    6    6
9     c    c    c
10    8    8    8
```

Here is one way to do it with Pandas [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html):

```py
# Add duplicates count for each row
df["quantity"] = 1
df["quantity"] = df.groupby(["col1", "col2", "col3"]).transform(sum)

# Remove duplicated rows except first one
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["col1", "col2", "col3"], keep="first").reset_index(
    drop=True
)
```

Then:

```py
  col1 col2 col3  quantity
0    a    a    a         3
1    1    1    1         1
2    8    8    8         3
3    3    3    3         1
4    c    c    c         2
5    6    6    6         1
```